# What is PPA for Firefox Developer Edition in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: firefox, ppa, 19.04

I've added two PPAs:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu
```

but still have no autoupdates for my FF Developer Edition, although FF says that it have a new build. However, language files are updated regularly. Could you please help me?

Comment: I can't find the first PPA, not sure if it still exists. The second PPA [does exist](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora), but last build was on March 15th, so it seems no one maintains it. Only the [beta PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next) is maintained. It is a good idea to check that a PPA has what you want, before adding it.

Comment: @mikewhatever I've removed my two PPAs and added yours - but still no updates :(

Comment: Which version do you have installed? Which version do you expect to get?

Comment: @mikewhatever I have 68.0b2 now, but I've update it manually from here https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

Comment: Yeap, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Firefox Developer Edition, formerly know as Aurora, like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: Well, it's the second PPA I've added, and still no updates. But! In the previous Ubuntu 18.04 these PPAs worked fine and I received an updates for FF Dev Edition.